# Как правильно вставить переменную в @import (SCSS)?

Tags: sass, scss

Решил изначально задать дефолтные адреса до папок. Далее в `@import` пробую вывести переменную с готовым адресом до папки - синтаксическая ошибка.

Имеется ли вообще возможность указывать переменные в `@import` и если да, то каким образом?

```
// PATH
$pathModules: 'modules';
$pathModulesStyles: #{$pathModules}'/css';

// INCLUDE MODULES
@import #{$pathModulesStyles}'/css/module-1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **@import** нельзя использовать переменные для импорта sass-файлов. Но можно для css (с url()).

https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/pravila_i_direktivi/direktiva_import.html